# how to set any browser to no keep alive in apache httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, http, httpd, httpd.conf

I have the following setting for IE in my httpd.conf:

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

I want to apply this to all requests that hit my server.

My httpd.conf section that deals with keep alive looks like this:

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 5

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive Off

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 1

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 1
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You should be able to do that in the server global or VirtualHost configuration, no?

Comment: that definitely *should* disable keepalives... It's not being turned on again somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable HTTP keep-alive for all browsers just [set `KeepAlive` to off globally](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive).

No sense wasting resources on a `BrowserMatch` if you don't have to, but if you really want to  use BrowserMatch just compose a regular expression that matches anything. `".*"` is a good one.

Comment: KeepAlive was already set to off.  Does the client need to do something to stop receiving a connection state of keep-alive after a http get is invoked?

Comment: If `KeepAlive` is Off and not overridden anywhere else then keep-alives should simply not work. I suspect there's more to this that you're not telling us -- what specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a client trying to do a get against a service I have.  It just returns a few characters.  I have posted all the parameters concerning the keep alive in the question above.

Comment: hmm... I'm not sure Keepalive is your problem, but you certainly appear to have it turned off. You can use my notes above to set HTTP/1.0 for all browsers and see if that helps. If not there may be something else going on...

Comment: I set MaxKeepAliveRequests to 0 and KeepAlive now stays off.

Comment: Note: If you set `MaxKeepAliveRequests` to `0` it means Unlimited requests per 1 connection. If you want to disable `KeepAlive`, set it to `Off` in global or virtual host's section.